# Isn't this rude? Or am I wrong?

Tags: phrases, writing-style

I recently saw this statement when I unsubscribed an email from DiGi.

> We're sorry to see you leave <strike>(but you know where to find us again
>   for the latest information, hot updates and news!)</strike>

Isn't the first part of the statement (if taken separately) rude or at least on a sarcastic tone? But then again I may be wrong.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What's DiGi? And was the second part crossed out in the original? If not, why is it crossed out here?

Comment: Why would it be rude/ sarcastic? Even a skeptical interpretation would not show negativity or anything but regret there. You are not wrong -- you must have just seen it from a defensive/ defective perspective.

Comment: Voting to close not constructive. This is a request for impressions of tone, that is to say, opinion. There's no right answer.

Comment: Related questions about the tone of apologies: [The act of using the word “sorry” outside of apologizing is called what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19334/the-act-of-using-the-word-sorry-outside-of-apologizing-is-called-what), [Does apologizing entail recognizing being at fault?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8999/does-apologizing-entail-recognizing-being-at-fault), [Are “Conditional apology” and “poisoned apology”, rude?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29874/are-conditional-apology-and-poisoned-apology-rude)

Answer (score 6):

No. It is meant to sound truly regretful. Whether you believe that they mean it or not is another question, but the phrase itself is polite and appropriate, as well as quite common.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also note that "leave" puts the onus on YOU for departing.  They could have said something to emphasize their own shortcomings ("We're sorry we couldn't provide what you were looking for" etc.) but they chose to paint a picture of you taking decisive, individual action while they merely observed (albeit, tearfully).

It certainly is a bit of verbal gymnastics.  Do you think a boss would accept an employee's excuse that a potential customer "chose to go elsewhere."  I bet she'd reply, "No.  YOU failed to close the deal!"